# How can I have my installer write to the HKCU registry tree?

Tags: installation, registry, user-accounts

My installer requires admin privileges. During installation some values are written to the HKCU tree of the registry of the currently logged on user. However, when this user account is a so called standard account, the user has to specify credentials for an administrator account when the installer starts. The values are then written to the HKCU tree pertaining to this admin account instead of the HKCU of the currently logged on user.
The same problem arises when the installer wants to write some data to the local AppData and wants to create a shortcut on the desktop.

How do I circumvent this?

Comment: Are you saying that the installer needs to be "Run as Administrator" or that the installer itself prompts for credentials so that it can impersonate the Administrator?

Comment: @ShiggityShiggityShwa The installer prompts for credentials when the logged on user is a standard Windows account. When the logged on user is an administrator account the UAC screen prompt appears.

Comment: Who do you require admin rights?

Comment: @Anders I need to write to the Program Files folder

Comment: @Dabblernl because you are installing a driver or service?

Comment: @Anders I need to install the Net 4 Framework and the Crystal Reports XI engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking for admin rights it normally means you are doing a system-wide/machine install for all users. When creating this type of installer it is not a good idea to write to HKCU or %USERPROFILE%, not just because you can end up performing actions for "the wrong user" but you also end up initializing the install for just that one user and not all users.

What I recommend is that you write this common data to `HKLM\Software\YourCompany\YourApp\CommonData` and/or `<CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA|CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES>\YourCompany\YourApp\CommonData` and then import this data in your application the first time a user run's it.

You might also want to consider creating a per-user installer (like Chrome) but this means you can **only** write to HKCU and %USERPROFILE%!

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you are using a per-machine installation which writes data in a per-user location (HKEY_CURRENT_USER).

The correct approach is to use either a per-user installation with only per-user locations or a per-machine installation with only per-machine locations (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE instead of HKEY_CURRENT_USER).