# Writing into administrator's HKCU from standard user

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, installation, registry, user-accounts

I have a installer created in visual studio 2010 which writes into HKCU of registry. It requires administrative privilege during both installation and running.

Now when I am installing it with administrative privilege, from a standard account the registry entries are written into standard user's HKCU registry part. But when I am running it with administrative privilege,it is reading from administrator's registry HKCU.

After lot of searching I came to the conclusion that when you run a program with elevated privilege, It searches for the elevated user's HKCU. But why same thing is not happening during Installation as I have administrative privilege at that time also.

According to another stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898589/how-can-i-have-my-installer-write-to-the-hkcu-registry-tree), opposite thing is happening, i.e. Elevated installation writes to admin's HKCU. Can anyone help me how to achieve that workaround.

[Note: I am aware that changing the code to read and write from HKLM ,rather than using HKCU may be best solution for this ,but not for me .Because recently it was changed from HKLM for another big issue and cannot be reverted.]

Comment: I'm guessing this is an MSI-based installer?  I think the behaviour you describe may be as-expected for MSI, because part of the installation is done in the user's context and part in the admin context.  Try launching the installer from an elevated command window.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, Can you please give some more details. I did not understand your suggestion about "Try launching the installer from an elevated command window". :/

Comment: Open the Start Menu and type `cmd` followed by `CONTROL-SHIFT-ENTER`.  This will open an elevated command window.  If you launch the MSI file from here, it will probably put the HKCU entries in the right place.

Comment: In my case; we want our elevated-background-service to load settings from not-elevated Frontend-App's HKCU, but seems no source-code-answer here.

Answer (score 0):

> Now when I am installing it with administrative privilege,

How do you actually start the installation? Do you have an EXE wrapper over your MSI and launch it with the command "Run as administrator"? Is that wrapper launching the MSI latter on during the installation?

Normally, if an MSI is launched by an elevated process (be it the EXE wrapper or a an elevated cmd.exe) the per-user data (registry and files) are redirected to the locations of the new user (i.e. the admin under which now the installer is running). So your registry entries should be created also under the administrator's HKCU hive and your application should find them when launched as an admin.

As a side discussion, is not really recommended to have an application load entries from HKCU but run it directly elevated, things can get confusing. If you want your app to run as admin, then you should install it per-machine and use the appropriate file and registry locations. What was the bug that made you guys switch to per-user installation? (maybe we can help with a better solution)

Comment: I have "Require administrator" option set on installer. So it asks for  Administrator password when I am trying to install it from standard user account. <>

I don't know the proper reason for change. As far as I know,the case is like, a part of the project is included in another project,which does not require any admin privilege and does not use registry. But as this small project is writing in HKLM registry, the whole installer was asking for administrative privilege. To avoid this, The whole registry is shifted to HKCU. Though I believe that was not the best option available.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but from what I understand now you have no project that needs admin privileges as you are working only with HKCU, why do you still ask for admin credentials? Regarding your original problem, can you maybe post a download link for your installer and a verbose of the installation you are doing? I would like to do some tests too (in a VM), as normally your EXE should pass the execution credentials to your MSI and the HKCU registry entries should be written in the same location from where the app tries to read them.

Comment: No. Actually there are three projects.Two large -one requires admin privilege for socket opening and other issues, another don't. Now there is another small project common to this two. Previously the small project and the project requiring admin privilege are using HKLM. But after integration of the small project, another project which does not require admin privilege, started requiring it to write to HKLM.

Comment: Sorry can't provide you any sample EXE. Company's property. :/

Comment: @Codename_DJ: what file do you actually run in order to do the installation?  Is it an .MSI file or an .EXE file?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, it is a MSI file. Sorry I mistakenly said exe.

Comment: @Codename_DJ: so, if you wrap the MSI file inside an EXE file, and set the EXE file to require admin privilege to run, it should behave the way you want it to.